# Use only verified addresses in production AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have AWS SES in production mode, but now want to limit sending to only verified addresses (as it did in sandbox mode).  Is there any way to configure this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, AWS SES has built-in email reputation checks and other filtering checks. Your application should decide which emails you are planning to send using the API. Otherwise, it'll anyway hit the API with a request perform that you are willing to block.

However, you can control your various AWS SES actions in many ways using AWS Identity and Access Management. Refer to the official doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/control-user-access.html
Look for the section "Restricting Email Addresses" in that doc.

If it's not the answer you are looking for, please comment with more information. I'll try my best to help. Take care.

---

FYI, long story short: log in to your AWS console to create an IAM policy for SES service. Add and apply policies to particular SES services. More details  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/control-user-access.html#iam-and-ses-examples-recipients

Comment: When the application was in development, SES restricted email sent to a small number of verified addresses.  When the app went into production, the request to move SES into production removed these restrictions.  For various reasons, I want to run it with those same restrictions.  I was hoping to do this without code changes.  Basically, change it back to pre-production mode with respect to email.  In the meantime, I DID make the needed code changes, but would still be curious to know if this is possible.

Comment: You can do that without programming. I made some updates in the original post. please review.